# Nginx, PHP - An error occurred. Sorry, the page you are looking for is currently unavailable. Please try again later

Tags: php, nginx

I get an error when I access my `index.php` of my `/usr/local/nginx-1.12.2/html`.

```
An error occurred.
Sorry, the page you are looking for is currently unavailable.
Please try again later.

If you are the system administrator of this resource then you should check the error log for details.

Faithfully yours, nginx.
```

---

My `nginx.conf` is this:

`# cat conf/nginx.conf`:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm index.php;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            root           html;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

    }

}
```

in my `/usr/local/php-7.1.16/etc`, the `php-fpm.conf` config is this:

`# cat php-fpm.conf`

```
[global]
pid = /usr/local/php-7.1.16/var/run/php-fpm.pid
error_log = /usr/local/php-7.1.16/var/log/php-fpm.log
log_level = notice

[www]
listen = /tmp/php-cgi.sock
listen.backlog = -1
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1
listen.owner = www
listen.group = www
listen.mode = 0666
user = www
group = www
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 60
pm.start_servers = 30
pm.min_spare_servers = 30
pm.max_spare_servers = 60
request_terminate_timeout = 100
request_slowlog_timeout = 0
slowlog = var/log/slow.log
```

My `php-fpm` is running. I can use `ps -ef | grep php-fpm` to check. there are multi processes at there.

my `index.php` is just a `phpinfo()`:

`index.php`:

```
<?php

  ini_set("display_errors","On");  
  error_reporting(E_ALL);    

  echo phpinfo(); 
?>
```

---

**EDIT-1**

In my nginx's `error.log`:

```
2018/06/25 09:36:02 [error] 12360#0: *13338 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 118.113.137.192, server: localhost, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "101.103.23.5"
```

---

**EDIT-2**

Thanks Dan, I changed the `fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000` to:

```
fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/php-cgi.sock;
```

But I get the `File not found.` error, when I access the `index.php`.

Comment: Check nginx logs to see what's exacly wrong.

Comment: _“If you are the system administrator of this resource then you should check the error log for details.”_ - why do we have to repeat for you what the error message already told you?

Comment: @CBroe I have updated in my post.

Comment: @Yupik See my Edit-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You specify a unix socket for fpm to listen:

```
listen = /tmp/php-cgi.sock
```

But in nginx you specify an IP address:

```
fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
```

---

Configure either IP only or Unix Socket only:

```
fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/php-cgi.sock;
```

or

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
```

---

Concerning your *edit 2*:

Try adding this param:

```
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
```

And also your `SCRIPT_FILENAME` does not look correct, the folder you specify most probably does not exist (`/scripts`).

Try this dynamic path:

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

Comment: You most probably don't have the folder `scripts` in the servers root `/`.

Comment: `/scripts` and `./scripts` and `scripts/` are 3 different things

Answer (score 0):

You should use the bellow configurations of `php` in nginx:

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
        root           html;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/php-cgi.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
```

The `$document_root$fastcgi_script_name` statement is invalid now.