# Ubuntu Server Nginx Error after rebooting the server

Tags: nginx, server

**An error occurred.
Sorry, the page you are looking for is currently unavailable.
Please try again later.
If you are the system administrator of this resource then you should check the error log for details.
Faithfully yours, nginx.**

I rebooted the server just before happening this using `sudo reboot now` since it is an ubuntu server. 
I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51020731/nginx-php-an-error-occurred-sorry-the-page-you-are-looking-for-is-currently) .I did not understand any of it unfortunately. Also I cant access any of the pages in the specific site of mine which is showing this error.

The error.log is empty on the location `/var/log/nginx`

error.log.1 has some logs which happens months ago. Same for access.log.1

I am not a network guy.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo service nginx status
sudo service nginx start
```

could be that for some reason nginx not started after reboot

Comment: It turns out that I need to wait a little bit more time than i have anticipated in order to complete the booting process. Everything seemed good after 30 minutes. Felt so strange .